# Code signal matrix problem solved, needs to be improved

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

This problem is from code signal and I solved it, The first solution entered worked but I want to know why the second doesn´t.

I am supposed to write a function that takes a matrix as an input and returns a sum of items that are not below a 0.

Here is an example of the matrix.

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1, 0], 
          [0, 5, 0, 1], 
          [2, 1, 3, 10]]
```

the output should be
`solution(matrix) = 9`

```
    function solution(matrix) {
    let sum =0  
    for(j=0;j<matrix[0].length;j++){
    for(let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
    if(matrix[i][j]==0){
    break
    }
    else{ 
    sum += matrix[i][j]
    }
    }
    }
    return sum
    }
```

this works but this other one has an error

```
    function solution(matrix) {
    let sum =0
    for(j=0;j<matrix[j].length;j++){
    for(let i=0;i<matrix.length;i++){
    if(matrix[i][j]==0){
    break
    }
    else{ 
    sum += matrix[i][j]
    }
    }
    }
    return sum
}
```

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at solution (<anonymous>:5:25)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

The problem is using the the variable as an index for the columns

I just want to know **why** the later did not work in order to learn

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the key difference is how the for loop is intiailized:

```
for (j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
```

vs

```
for (j = 0; j < matrix[j].length; j++)
```

The order of execution in a for loop is:

- Start at `j = 0`
- check `j < matrix[j].length`. If the statement evaluates to true, execute the block between `{...}`
- increment using `j++`

When `j = 3`, `matrix[j].length = 4` and the block executes, followed by `j++`.

Now `j = 4`, but `matrix[j]` does not exist (`undefined`), and hence the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`.

You may find this useful:
[What is the exact order of execution of Javascript's for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664531/what-is-the-exact-order-of-execution-of-javascripts-for-loop)